# Reed switch or Hall effect for motorcycle speedometer?

Tags: sensor, speed, hall-effect

I'm trying to build a speedometer for my motorcycle using an Arduino and I'm not sure whether to use a reed switch or a Hall sensor. The sensing distance is about 5-10 cm (the distance between the wheel and the sensor / switch).
The only sensor I can get is a 3144 one (that's all the information I got about it...)

Is the distance too great for sensing? It only needs to check if the magnet is around the sensor, nothing more.

Comment: Why such a large distance?

Comment: reed switches have moving parts that limit longevity and bandwidth.

Comment: @Andyaka that s the closest safe distance that i can get between the fork and the wheel unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hall sensor may be best; most are designed to be robust. Many have threads or mounting brackets to make it easier to attach to your system like this:

https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/gt1-series-hall-effect-gear-tooth-sensors/13172

As mentioned before, if you use magnets instead of detecting the metal passing by from a gear tooth or something, you can extend the range.

Reed switches rely on mechanical motion to send a pulse meaning some form of wear. They aren't designed to handle fast switching action over long periods of time.

Comment: Interestingly, bicycle computers usually use reed switches, perhaps for long service life on a coin cell.   But they tend to go slower with larger wheels, so a motorcycle may see a few times faster actuation frequency.

Answer (score 4):

A reed switch is not generally a good choice in a high vibration environment.  Shocks may cause undesired closing of the switch.  You could explore anti-vibration mounting, but it's basically the wrong solution.

A Hall effect sensor makes more sense here.  5cm is not too great a distance, finding magnets strong enough shouldn't be a problem.

You need more information than a partial part number to use a part properly.  You're probably referring to the A3144.  Google it and you'll find datasheets.  The part seems to have been discontinued, by the way.